# Inserting JSON Text into DB2 Table

Tags: sql, json, db2

I was able to follow and apply [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1087995/Inserting-JSON-Text-into-SQL-Server-Table) to extract data from JSON object and inserting it to my table using MS SQL server, however I am trying to do the same using DB2 and could not find any articles or posts that shows how to select data from a JSON object and then to insert in a table with DB2. And I am wondering if there is a way to do so.

Comment: If you want DB2, why have you tagged SQL Server?

Comment: because I am looking for something in DB2 similar to SQL

Comment: Yeah but just because someone familiar with SQL Server doesn't mean they have any knowledge at all about DB2, and if they do, they will monitor the DB2 tag. Please only tag the relevant RDBMS in future.

Comment: Which version of Db2? Db2 can store JSON objects, you can also process JSON objects and transform them into relational data. What do you want? See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=json-sql-access-documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 offers the `JSON_TABLE` function just like `OPENJSON` from MSSQL.

https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/systems/articles/i-json-table-trs/